# Google Login fail with youtube accounts

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, google-authentication

I have an application that use Google Login for get the information of the YouTube channel (upload videos, subscriptions, etc...). When the user tries to login, they can select from a list of Google accounts and after  from a list of Youtube channels if the user have more than one. But, when a YouTube channel is selected, the API fails.

```
var login = function(options) {
```

`if (!gapi.auth2){
    // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: config.credentials.googleApiClientId,
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
      });
    });
  }

  var GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  return GoogleAuth.signIn(options);

};`

And in the callback JavaScript Google API says:

> Object {type: "tokenFailed", idpId: "google", error: "USER_LOGGED_OUT"}

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar problem, after awhile of experimentation I got this to work, I am not entirely sure what was the problem the things I changed is adding `prompt: 'select_account'` to the `signIn` call options and `fetch_basic_profile: false` to the `init` call options:

Here's a [jsbin that might work for you](http://jsbin.com/veqaxeg/1/edit), make sure to add your own client_id to the init call and make sure to whitelist output.jsbin.com domain and preview the jsbin from that domain.

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
  client_id: '',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  fetch_basic_profile: false,
  cookie_policy: 'single_host_origin'
});


auth2.signIn({
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  prompt: 'select_account'
}).then(function(result) {
  console.log('Signed in!');
  console.log(result);
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! In my case it was not working because I was missing `scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` in the google API initialization code.  
I took my code straight from Google API documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/ > "Try this API" > "Show code" but it did not contain that line...